# Why and how would I protect struct members from direct manipulation in C

Tags: c, struct

Let's say we have the following code in a .h file:

```
typedef struct
{
  float velocity[2];
  float position[2];
  float rotation;
} Bullet;


void Bullet_init(Bullet *bullet, float position[2], float velocity[2], float rotation)
{
  bullet->rotation = rotation;
  bullet->velocity[0] = velocity[0];
  bullet->velocity[1] = velocity[1];
  bullet->position[0] = position[0];
  bullet->position[1] = position[1];
  return;
}
```

If a programmer includes this file in his code, couldn't he simply modify the struct directly with bullet.velocity[2] = 5 instead of using the Bullet_init function? Do we simply need to trust that the programmer will use the functions properly? In C++, you can just create a class with private members that can only be touched with member functions. This isn't that simple with C. Does it even matter?

Comment: If you do not publish the prototype of the struct, people will have to use the functions to manipulate the bullet type.

Comment: Why are you including the definition of the function Bullet_init() in a header file?  Header files are for declarations, not definitions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C you have to either trust the programmer or make the struct definition not be part of a public interface.

You could for example have (in a header file):

```
typedef struct some_struct some_struct;
int some_struct_get_member(some_struct * ptr);
void some_struct_set_memember(some_struct * ptr, int newValue);
```

And then in your .c file:

```
#include <assert.h>

struct some_struct { int member; };

int some_struct_get_member(struct some_struct * ptr) {
    assert(ptr);
    return ptr->member;
}

void some_struct_set_member(struct some_struct * ptr, int newValue) {
    assert(ptr);
    ptr->member = newValue;
}
```

As for why you might do this, if the struct has complicated internal requirements having it so that only a limited interface manipulates those internals helps ensure that the values always make sense.

Comment: It would be a good idea to use `some_struct const *` for the parameter type of the read-only functions